Can a travel agent abuse personal information they have on me?
Recently I had an unpleasant experience with a travel agent. His agency did visa assistance work. I emailed my UK refusal letter and other documents like NOC and cover letter, which I used for applying to the UK.
He changed his mind to help me saying they catered corporate clients only and not individual clients. He was also very rude. I felt very insulted. I just said thank you and left.
My NOC had sensitive details like passport and civil ID number. Can he send this to VFS Global and ask them to deny me or not entertain me for applying? I mean what jurisdictions or connections do travel agents have with VFS Global? Can they email and tell the embassy?

What country are you in?

I m in the middle east. Uae

If by "travel agent" you mean someone who plans and books travel for you then they have ZERO jurisdiction with VFS or UK Immigration. Also they generally know almost nothing about how to apply for a visa, except the mechanics of filling in the forms. Especially they don't know how to help you in difficult cases.

@DJClayworth No, the OP apparently means something else by the words "travel agent." The work of the OP's agent is described in the question as "visa assistance." This is not a "travel agent" as the phrase is usually understood (i.e., buying tickets and arranging itineraries), but instead a rôle referred-to here as a "visa agent," a person who is expected to provide advice to the visa applicant, perhaps to complete the applicant's application...and is frequently found to be incompetent or dishonest.

Yes they fill forms for people.an take appointments. Its a travel agency where one guy usually does the visa assistance work. So i would like to know if any details that i have emailed him might be used against me?

@Mohd If they're criminals, sure, they can abuse your personal data.  If they're non-criminals, they will not.

No theyre a licensed travel agency. But due to them being rude with me i had a small argument with them in defense. Can they email the german embassy from where i got a visa recently and have travelled a month ago or as vfsglobal?

@Mohd You can't control what the people do.  However, with that said, it would be extremely unlikely that someone would be vindictive enough to email the german embassy just because you had an argument with them.  In my opinion you should stop worrying about minor possibilities, and focus on what things actually happen.

Can the travel agency tell the german embassy my noc and payslip is fake? I already have travelled to germany after getting the visa last month.

Are your NOC and payslip fake? If not, why are you worried?

Unfortunately, people have very mixed feelings about the VFS. In some countries e.g. where I stay(Norway), they are really professional, nice and helpful. On the contrary, the folks in the UK sit on the other side of the fence. They are neither professional nor very cooperative (Check out the Google Reviews of VFS-Edinburgh). In the end, it all comes down to person to person and administrative staff of the VFS center you are visiting. Racism element cannot be overlooked as well. Sorry, but it is true.
Regarding your concerns, it is very unlikely that your case would be highlighted. Travel agent/VFS handles hundreds of clients everyday. And since we all are unique, and everyone has different temperament, meaning our interaction with VFS could also vary regardless of the visa outcome.
I would suggest you not to overthink. And if possible, consider reapplying addressing the areas that lead to rejection of your visa.

@Mohd I agree with Naveed Ahmed that you are over-thinking this. VFS-Global is not in the business (and is not getting paid for) keeping and sharing lists of customers with whom the agent has had disagreements. Without a pending application, government consular offices will not be interested either. If you need help in responding to a visa denial from Germany, I suggest you find a different and more capable and cooperative agent.

If someone knew the ambassador of some country and emailed bad about me would it make a difference ?
